# AzerothCore - Stuck at 'Connected' after logging in

Tags: azerothcore

I seem to have an intermittant issue logging into my own AC server. There are only 4 people that use it, and it has been running for a few weeks. However, there is an intermittant issue where we can get stuck at the 'connected' message while logging in.

My realmlist table is set up correctly, as most of the time the system works.

Steps taken:
-Enter correct username and password
-user is authenticated
-system messages cycle: 'handshaking' > 'Connected'

This should then complete and I should be connected to the world server and see my character list.

However, it does not progress beyond 'Connected'. This some times lasts for several monutes before connecting, or some times the session can time out and the connection is closed.

Does anyone know, or is there any debugging I can enable to see what the issue may be?

I have seen old posts about trunkating instance_reset, however, those are over 4 years old and I am not sure why that would work or if it would cause any damage.

Answer (score 0):

Being stuck at connected usually indicates issues with networking. Make sure there is no firewall preventing the forwarding from auth to the worldserver. Limitations with the allowed amount of connections could cause it.
I recommend working through the `networking` section of the AC wiki and eliminating all possible causes 1 by 1.

Comment: thanks
The networking section basically covers
-Bindip - Set to 0.0.0.0 to bind on all i/f
-auth/realm Port fwd - must be correct as it works most of the time.
-Firewall - Must be correct as it works most of the time. 
-Realmlist – Using fqdn, must be correct as it works most of the time.
Any bad config above would cause 100% attempt failure.

I tried checking for long running queries (e.g. retrieving character list) in MySQL8 DB with ‘show processlist;’. The DB was mostly idle.
Wondered if it was a slow response from the worldserver, but I am not able to see anything in either log.

Comment: On most systems, including windows, you need to add an explicit exception for the worldserver and authserver binaries. "Works most of the time" is not an indication that it's gonna work with another file.